# Cannot call a method from a class in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#

I have developed the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ESROWCFData
{

 public class ESROWFCData
 {
    public string GetNCAMSData()
     {
        //int iOffset = 0, iTake = 0;
        string strOffset = "iOffset", strTake = "iTake";

        string strNCAMS = "SELECT * FROM[HRO_REPORTS].[dbo].NCAMS WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, VisitStartDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GetDate()) ORDER BY VisitorID OFFSET " + strOffset + " rows fetch next " + strTake + " rows only";

        return strNCAMS;
     }
 }
}
```

and have included the `using ESROWCFData;` statement in my main program but when I try to call the `GetNCAMSData()` function it does not show up and I get the error that it does not exist. I am obviously doing something wrong but I cannot see what it is.

Comment: new ESROWFCData().GetNCAMSData() :)

Comment: where is it you wanna call your method? That's the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here. You can either make the method static so you can call it without creating an instance of your class by changing the signature to be:

```
public static string GetNCAMSData()
```

Then call it like this:

```
var result = ESROWFCData.GetNCAMSData()
```

Or you could create a new instance of the class and then call it off that like follows

```
var instance = new ESROWFCData(); 
var result = instance.GetNCAMSData()
```

Comment: Brilliant. Please accept the answer to mark to question as closed and allow others with similar issues to get help too. @donald.dougherty

Answer (score 1):

You first have to create an instance of the `ESROWFCData` class:

```
ESROWFCData data = new ESROWFCData();
```

and then use it:

```
string s = data.GetNCAMSData();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your namespace and class name are the same :

```
namespace ESROWCFData
{
    public class ESROWFCData
    {
        ...
```

So even if you want to use this class outside you have to use full type name :

```
ESROWCFData.ESROWCFData data = new ESROWCFData.ESROWCFData();
```

In case you're trying to use it like such :

```
ESROWCFData data = new ESROWCFData();
```

Compiler then is confused because of that namespace name.
Consider name changes on the namespace or class to resolve that issue.
[More about that issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/)

---

Another issue is ( the one we do not know much about ) how are you trying to call that object's method. If you want to just use them statically, mark it as static :

```
namespace ESROWCFData
{
    public class ESROWCFData
    {
        public static string GetNCAMSData()
        {
            ...
```

And you can call them like so : `ESWROWCFData.ESWROWCFData.GetNCAMSData()`